# Reordering content using a meta value

Tags: wp-query, join-tables

I've got this theme where you can add posts of type "portfolio", and I want to be able to reorder them up. I've added a custom meta field called "position" and I've set already those values. All good.

My question is: How can I modify the query to join the wp_postmeta table and order them by the "postion" value?

This is the current query:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'posts_per_page' => $homepagenumber
) );
```

I really appreciate any hint on this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [WP_Query Order by Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

```
 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',
   'meta_key' => 'age',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
   'order' => 'ASC',
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'age',
           'value' => array(3, 4),
           'compare' => 'IN',
       )
   )
 );
 $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

PS.-I tried voting your answer up but I couldn't :( (need some reputations points)